# How to update listview in tab?

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I have two tabs in my app and there are listviews in this tabs.

I set List data to each listvew.

[image]

I want to delete form list, and from listview when I click [x] image.

Item deleted from list In my code , but I dont know how to update listview,I use `notifyDataSetChanged()` in my customadapter,  but not update.

Activity for first tab:

```
public static List<Product> mCartList;
mCartList = AllProducts.getCartList();
        listViewCatalog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_order_list);
        mProductAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(MyOrders.this, mCartList, "", true);
        listViewCatalog.setAdapter(mProductAdapter);
```

my Custom List Adapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Product> mProductList;
    private String mType;
    private boolean mShowQuantity;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, List<Product> list, String type, boolean showQuantity) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mContext = context;
        mProductList = list;
        mShowQuantity = showQuantity;
        mType = type;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mProductList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mProductList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder item;
        final int finalMPosition = position;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            item = new ViewHolder();

            item.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
            item.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            item.pid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pid);
            item.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            item.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);

            item.removeProduct = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.removeProduct);
            item.addToCart = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addtocard);
            item.productQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantity);

            convertView.setTag(item);
        } else {
            item = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final Product curProduct = mProductList.get(position);
        item.imageView.setImageDrawable(curProduct.imageView);
        item.name.setText(curProduct.name);
        item.pid.setText(curProduct.pid);
        int length = curProduct.description.length();
        int start = 0, end = length;
        if (length >= 40) {
            start = 0;
            end = 40;
        }
        String s = curProduct.description.substring(start, end);
        item.description.setText(s + "...");
        item.price.setText(curProduct.price + mContext.getString(R.string.currency));


        if (mShowQuantity) {
            item.addToCart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            item.productQuantity.setText("Quantity: " + AllProducts.getProductQuantity(curProduct));
            item.productQuantity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            item.productQuantity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            item.removeProduct.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        item.removeProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                ab.setTitle("Delete ");
                ab.setMessage("This product will be deleted from list.").setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        curProduct.selected = false;
                        AllProducts.removeProduct(curProduct);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                ab.create().show();
            }
        });

        item.addToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent productDetailsIntent = new Intent(mContext, ProductDetail.class);
                productDetailsIntent.putExtra(AllProducts.PRODUCT_INDEX, finalMPosition);
                productDetailsIntent.putExtra("type", mType);
                mContext.startActivity(productDetailsIntent);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView pid;
        TextView addToCart;
        TextView name;
        TextView price;
        TextView description;
        ImageView imageView;
        ImageView removeProduct;
        TextView productQuantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code of your custom adapter. Actually `notifyDataSetChanged()` will do exactly what you want per title of your question - update listview

Comment: Where are ya calling the notifyDataSetChanged() method ?

Comment: +50 bounty for answer! after tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem.

```
public static void setTab(int i){
    if(i==0){
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(i+1);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(i);
    }
    else{
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(i-1);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(i);
    }
}
```

and

```
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    curProduct.selected = false;
                    AllProducts.removeProduct(curProduct);
                    MyTabActivity.setTab(0);
                }
```

and for second listview:

```
MyTabActivity.setTab(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the list view or you can reset the setAdapter() which the new list values , but later one will be costly

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different `List`, try doing this:

Create a constructor without passing a `List` i mean:

```
       CustomListAdapter(MyOrders.this, "", true);
```

Then in the CustomListAdapter create an List Local variable and instatiate it in the constructor:

```
private List<Product> mProductList;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, String type, boolean showQuantity) {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mContext = context;
    mProductList = new ArrayList<Product>();
    mShowQuantity = showQuantity;
    mType = type;
}
```

then create an Add or Delete method in the `CustomListAdapter`:

```
public void AddItem(Product product){
   if(null != product){
    mProductList.add(product);
  }
 }
```

Then an updateMethod too:

```
public void update(){
mProductList.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: where I must put "public void update(){
mProductList.notifyDataSetChanged();
}"

Comment: @SardorDushamov In the CustomListAdapter class

Comment: What i mean is that create all the method that modify the List inside the CustomListAdapter, so you modify the list that is used for creating the views too.

Comment: Did you create an erase method in the CustomListAdapter and erased the item in the on click listener and called update?

Comment: please see above, i posted code of my custom adapter , this line starts 'item.removeProduct.setOnClickListener...'

Comment: I see the problem, you're getting an position and then sending it away, try to erase that position directly with the List and call notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

The only reason it is not working for you now, is because you have two different lists. You are removing from wrong list.

So first of all, do not delete from your list. Write a method in your adapter where you remove it from list you have stored in that Adapter, and then call notifyDatasetChanged in that method.

Comment: there are two listview in tab, when i click remove image, removed from List<Prodct>, but i need update  after that

Comment: you removed from List<Product> but I suggested you to remove it from list which is stored in CustomAdapter.
Can you provide Complete Code of Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

if  notifyDatasetChanged is not working try to use this

```
yourlist.invalidateviews();
```

Comment: here is a piece of code on my app to delete and update listview listView.remove(position);
notifyDataSetChanged(); or listView.invalidateview();

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove that particular item from arraylist by calling

```
AllProducts.remove(position);
notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Comment: I did that, item removed from arraylist, but listview not updated

Answer (score 0):

write this methode in your adapter and use it to remove perticular Item from adapter.

```
public void remove(int position){
    mProductList.remove(position);
    notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with tabs in android 2.x, I found a bug in the emulator: The tabs are not correctly refreshed or removed. Alternatives is to use support library v7 which as support for action bar tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to update `ListView`.
In order to update `ListView` you must have to call `notifyDataSetChanged();` menthod on `Adapter`. See Below code.

What you did.

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```

What you have to do is,

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Or you may use following code to refresh your list.

```
private List<Object> mCarlistitem= new ArrayList<Object>();
public void refreshlist()
    {
        mCarlistitem.clear();
        for(int i=0; i< mCartList.size(); i++)
        {
            Object object = new Object();           
            mCarlistitem.add(object);
        }
         mProductAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(MyOrders.this, mCartList, "",true);
         listViewCatalog.setAdapter(mProductAdapter);

    }
```